# Combine Sum with select join and union

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum, union

I need to join 2 query like this

```
SELECT * from contracts join customers on customer.id=contracts.customer
```

and (12234 is an explample customer)

```
SELECT *,sum(cast(amount as UNSIGNED)) as total FROM(    
SELECT * from invoices
where customer='123456'
UNION
SELECT * from paypal_invoices
where customer='123456') t1
```

In the first query I simply extract a normal customers list based on the actives contracts we have.

In the second i extract the sum of any invoice for a specific customers

So i basically need to extract all customers like the first query but i need also a column with the sum of all invoice for this specific customer.
Thank you.

Comment: you're not asking a question... what happens when you run the query?

Comment: queries works good but i need to fuse them together for example order customers of the first query by the total of the second query....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is correlated subqueries or `left join`s:

```
select co.*, cu.*, i.amount, pi.amount as paypal_amount,
       ( coalesce(i.amount, 0) + coalesce(pi.amount, 0) ) as total       
from contracts co join
     customers cu
     on cu.id = co.customer left join
     (select customer, sum(amount) as amount
      from invoices
      group by customer
     ) i
     on i.customer = cu.id left join
     (select customer, sum(amount) as amount
      from paypal_invoices
      group by customer
     ) pi
     on pi.customer = cu.id;
```

Two key ideas here.  First, be sure that you aggregate before doing the joins.  This prevents joins from multiplying the number of rows and generating incorrect results.  Similarly, this uses `LEFT JOIN` to ensure that all customers are included, even those with no invoices.

Second idea:  Don't use `UNION`.  Your query, in fact, is possibly incorrect.  `UNION` removes duplicates -- both within a table and between tables.  It is much safer to use `UNION ALL`.  Or, in this case, it is not needed at all.